# Debian: Kernel update using APT - reboot required to take effect?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, patch-management

Suppose I update the kernel of a running Debian system using `apt-get upgrade linux-image-amd64` to a higher minor version number (e.g., `5.10.10` to `5.10.11`). Do I have to reboot the Debian server in order for the update to take effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, usually the kernel update is not done in-place so a reboot is needed to update the running kernel.

You might want to try `needrestart` via

```
sudo needrestart -kr l
```

It will check if the correct kernel is loaded (`-k`) and will only show an info and not do the restart itself (`-r l`). See `needrestart --help` for more info.

Comment: Nice, but is checking `/var/run/reboot-required` not much easier?